# xcode-select -switch path when using cli toolkit

Tags: xcode, path, toolkit

With the release of Apple's Command Line Toolkit for Xcode, I am trying to avoid needing to install Xcode proper. In order to do this, I need to set the path to xcode for specific make files that depend on the xcode-select path (which is currently pointing to /Developer)

Where do I point the xcode-select path when using the CLI Toolkit for Xcode?

If I install Xcode, it's just `/Applications/Xcode.app`, but I don't know where the CLI Toolkit is being placed.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

It appears from the pkg installer that it dumps it all to /usr/bin and then xcode-select or other scripts internal to the pkg create the paths for xcodebuilder etc. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: is this the case if I haven't installed Xcode.app? Or does the CLI Toolkit install to Xcode.app?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer if your only need gcc or etc.

Comment: you save me! mac ports suggests to run `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app` which makes no sense :(

Comment: so i still want to know, does the xcodebuild tool get installed to /Applications/Xcode.app if I dont install Xcode. It doesnt seem to make sense that it would.

Comment: This may be obvious, but if you have installed XCode Beta version you need to run `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer` instead.

Comment: Your answer is loook same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/9600674/11077258 this answer

Comment: @deadrunk You don't need to use the path to `Developer`. Just setting the path as mac ports indicates also works.

Answer (score 33):

I installed the CLI tools only (e.g. no Xcode) and received an error with a native gem extension build:

> xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected. Use `xcode-select -switch <path-to-xcode>`, or see the xcode-select manpage (`man xcode-select`) for further information.

After looking at this and browsing the directories, it appears the BSD tools got installed in `/usr/bin` therefore:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /
```

seems to work.

Comment: Worked for me using MacOs Lion version and the Xcode CLI dpk installer. Thanks!

Comment: if you run: "$ sudo xcode-select -p" it will show:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

Answer (score 19):

Just did this today after removing Xcode to reclaim HD space. I used:

```sh
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this problem recently because I had several XCode versions installed on the same machine. If you have one or more XCode previously installed, you can simply reset the path with the command:

```
sudo xcode-select -r
```

This will reset the path to the default, which is `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.

Answer (score 1):

For my setup (Xcode 4.0.2 on 10.6.8), I used spotlight to search for 'xcodebuild' to find where the Xcode CLI tools actually live.

The CLI tools are in /Developer/usr/bin, so my xcode-select command looks like (the /usr/bin is appended by xcode-select):

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Developer
```