# Xcode stops working after set "xcode-select -switch"

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

OMG, what I've done?

Couple of days ago, I tried using macport to install something, because I'm using Xcode 4.3 and the command-line tool hadn't been installed by the time, macport wouldn't work. So I followed some guide to get command-line tool installed, then I used following command:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/
```

which I think screwed everything except macport: now, in Xcode, even a simple single-view iOS project won't be compiled, it says "UIKit/UIKit.h not found".

Does anyone know how to correct this? I don't want to re-install the gigantic Xcode again, gotta do some iOS project tonight, help!

Answer (score 326, accepted):

You should be pointing it towards the `Developer` directory, not the Xcode application bundle.  Run this:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

With recent versions of Xcode, you can go to *Xcode* ➙ *Preferences…* ➙ *Locations* and pick one of the options for Command Line Tools to set the location.

Comment: ON running the above command i get error : xcode-select: Error: Path "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" is not a directory

Comment: @VikasSingh Even i am getting the same error. Were you able to solve it

Comment: @VikasSingh + abhishek the path will differ based on where you have xcode installed. For example if your xcode is called "Xcode 5.0.app" then the path would be: /Applications/Xcode\ 5.0.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: With recent versions of Xcode, go to *Xcode > Preferences… > Locations* and pick one of the options for *Command Line Tools* to set the location.

Comment: @jim, maybe updating the answer with your last comment would be useful?

Comment: What hierarchical structure of the folder should be to fullfill the need of `xcode-select`?

Comment: With Xcode 14 you have to run Xcode at least once and only then will the cli tools work (if the Xcode path is selected of course).