# Xcode 4.6 and Xcode 5 installed together

Tags: ios, xcode

Can we install Xcode 4.6 and xcode 5 on same machine without upgrading from xcode 4.6 to xcode 5?

Comment: In short Yes you can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you install the Xcode 5 Developer Preview in parallel with Xcode 4.6.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047449/can-you-install-the-xcode-5-developer-preview-in-parallel-with-xcode-4-6-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can install multiple versions of Xcode. They will install into separate directories. I've found that the best practice is to install the version that came with your Mac first, and then install downloaded versions, but it probably doesn't make a big difference. See this Apple Developer Connection page for lots of details.

It's easy to have multiple XCode installs.

In the installer there's a pulldown for the location... you just need to pick a new location when you're installing the beta version.

These instructions from an Apple dev tools evangelist have the full details (Apple dev username/password required): https://devforums.apple.com/message/40847#40847

Then grab yourself a custom icon for the Beta version of XCode you're using, so you can tell them apart in the dock: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/multiple-developer-tool-installs.html

Comment: I have installed both xcode on application just rename first version 4.6 to Xcode 4.6 and add new one which is Xcode and then rename to Xcode 5

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to create separate folders for different versions of Xcode, which I find provides a little more organization than renaming each Xcode release.

My folder layout looks as follows:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app
/Applications/Xcode4.6/Xcode.app
/Applications/Xcode5.0/Xcode.app
```

Simply create the necessary folders and drag/drop the relevant Xcode version into the same. You can also download older versions of Xcode from http://developer.apple.com/downloads/ and follow the same idea.

With the folder structure approach, from within a script (e.g. bash shell) you can move between versions of XCode with the xcode-select command line utility by simply specifying the desired folder:

```
$sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode4.6/Xcode.app
```

Change the release number in the command line to switch to a different version.

Comment: xcode-select should be pointing to the Developer folder, not the application folder. see this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600615/xcode-stops-working-after-set-xcode-select-switch

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just be sure of having two different names for them!

Comment: Thanks I will check now!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can because both can be installed and run simultaneously.

Create a folder with XCode 4 for example and keep XCode 5 in Application Folder.

But, with XCode 5 you can use the property of XCode 4 using iOS 6 sdk. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912484/xcode-5-does-not-see-devices-with-ios-6-1-3/18912834#18912834).